# Arrays with ordinal set of values for index?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I am pulling my hair over this one.

I read in my data structures text, that the index of an array usually uses a consecutive range of integers, ***but the index can have any ordinal set of values***.

I think I understand the consecutive range part, like 0,1,2...(in most languages) positions in an array where elements are placed, but what does an ordinal set of values mean?

*EDIT*

Here's a paragraph from the text:

**"In computer programming, a group of homogeneous elements of a specific data type is know as an array. Arrays hold a series of data elements, usually of the same size and data type. The individual elements are accessed by their position in the array. This position is given by an index, also called the subscript. The index usually uses a consecutive range of integers, but the index can have any ordinal set of values."**

Comment: An index of an array is usually just a non-negative integer value. Can you edit the question with the entire sentence verbatim from the textbook?

Comment: What is the context? Is it from a general CS introduction? Does this text favor a specific language for examples?

Answer (score 0):

It means, that usually array is indexed like `[0, 1, 2, 3, ... k]`, but it may happen, that some particular array data-structure, can have a ordinal set of index values - index values can be like `[1, 3, 5, 7.. k]`.